# Questions on enrolling Mok on ubuntu running from external drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, uefi

Before I start into asking questions I want to give a bit of background on what I am trying to so.

I recently got a new company laptop which runs windows 10. Being a company laptop it's highly locked down. It has bitlocker enabled  blocks many websites and I cannot install any applications etc. which is fair enough considering the company pay for it. I have some access to the uefi setup however I cannot make many if any changes and secure boot is permanently enabled and there is no legacy bios support.

I am going to be eventually commuting for about 2.5 hours each day and would like to be able to use this laptop for personal work during this time (as carrying 2 laptops is impractical), without the restrictions currently enabled in the windows 10.

My plan was to do a full install of Ubuntu 20.04 on an external ssd and connect it to the thunderbolt 3 usb port on the laptop and boot from this so I can do personal work for my commute time, I have this working currently on a USB 2.0 flash drive that I had to hand for testing, I installed the ubuntu from virtual box on my old personal laptop so that all the partitions efi root and home are on the usb stick along with some swap space. I followed a guide I found to end able uefi, legacy boot and to have the installation encrypted.

This boots fine in the new laptop. I enter the boot options menu and select the usb stick to boot rather than the internal ssd and it loads Ubuntu and when I am done I remove the usb and when I restart windows loads up fine using the windows bootloader.

The only issue I am running into is in regards to proprietary drivers and secure boot, I can install the driver fine but then it prompts me to enroll an mok on next boot. I have some experience with linux but prior to now I just disabled secure boot but I do not have this option any more and I am not too familiar with linux and secure boot.

My question is if I enroll the Mok from the external ubuntu installation into the firmeware is there any chance it will mess up the current windows installation on the internal drive or cause issues with this booting?

Correct me if I am wrong or if I am over simplifying this but from what I understand when I enroll the mok from the ubuntu it will enable the proprietary drivers to load in secure boot but when I remove the usb stick and then go to boot into windows from the internal drive will secure boot detect this key and prevent it from booting or is it a case that only the keys needed in for that specific windows installation will be used and any additional will be ignored? Since I cannot troubleshoot with windows 10 boot in any way I need to be sure that I will not be affected or I will have some explaining to do to the IT department.

Some other things to note, I might be using this on other hardware but to my knowledge it will all be without secure boot enabled so I should not have any issues.

Thanks for taking the time to read this and for any help you can give me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it should be a problem. See below. Best regards

"Machine Owner Key (MOK) is not part of the UEFI Secure Boot standard. MOK is used by Linux implementations. MOK functions identically to the DB and becomes initialized by the pre-bootloader Shim. Linux distributions utilize MOK keys to sign their own binaries rather than utilizing the process of having Microsoft or Original Equipment Manufacturers (OEM) sign every update or variation.

Microsoft signs Shim, Shim sets up MOK, MOK validates the second bootloader (commonly GRUB), MOK validates the Linux kernel, and MOK validates kernel modules. Most computing products available today do not ship with a Linux distribution KEK or DB certificate – Shim creates a software solution to a firmware limitation driven by market share.

**Shim is usually found on Linux systems and not found on Windows systems. MOK and MOKX do not exert any enforcement action until the Bootloader Phase of UEFI Boot (i.e. boot devices, OROMs, and firmware modules are not checked against MOK and MOKX).**"

Source: https://media.defense.gov/2020/Sep/15/2002497594/-1/-1/0/CTR-UEFI-Secure-Boot-Customization-UOO168873-20.PDF